# Медленное сокрытие action bar

Tags: java, android

Использую toolbar и надо сделать медленное скрытие и так же раскрытие, при использовании actionBar.hide() она резко появляется и так же резко исчезает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно использовать анимацию.

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547550/2293954):

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```